# Force windows to swap application

Tags: java, memory, swap

Hi 
I am debugging a Java application that fails when certain operations are invoked after VM memory is swapped to disk. Since I have to wait about an hour for windows to swap I was wondering if there is a way of forcing windows into swapping

Comment: Its generally a bad idea for a Java application to be swapped to disk. I would make sure you system always has enough memory soo it is never swapped to disk.

Answer (score 2):

You can create another application that allocates and accesses a large amount of memory. Assuming that you don't have enough memory for both to run, Windows will be forced to swap the inactive app to make room for the active app.

But before you do that, you might find help if you describe the exact problem that you're having with your app (including stack traces and sample code). The likelihood of swapping causing any problems other than delays is infinitesimally low.